# WinUI Desktop app publish in app center: Problem occurred while extracting your app

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-app-center, winui-3, visual-studio-app-center-distribute

I am trying to upload a WinUI desktop package in appcenter, but i am facing a below issue when uploading the packages.

[image]

In addition, I have tried some other app create options, all the way leads to the same error.

Can you please tell how to publish winui desktop (.msixbundle or zipped .msixbunde) in app center?

Also, please suggest which option to choose for WinUI Desktop app publishing?

[image]

**Note:** I have already published the WinUI UWP app in app center, must publish a WinUI desktop package.

Comment: I don't think app center supports WinUI3 Desktop yet. As of 3/27/2022 they only list UWP, WPF and WinForms.

Answer (score 0):

App center still does not support WinUI 3 Desktop Apps. (5/4/2022)
Hopefully coming soon.
As of today the website just shows support for "UWP, WPF and WinForms"
https://appcenter.ms/